# Why does IndexOf Soft hyphen returns 0 as a string?

Tags: c#, indexof, soft-hyphen

If you call `IndexOf` with the [soft hyphen](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/00ad/index.htm) character as parameter, it will work as expected:

```
"aaa".IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(173)) // return -1
"aaa\u00AD".IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(173)) // return 3
```

However, if you call the exact same code using the soft hyphen as a string, the returned value will be 0 even if there's no soft hyphen in the string.

```
"aaa".IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(173).ToString()) // return 0
"aaa\u00AD".IndexOf(Convert.ToChar(173).ToString()) // return 0
```

Why does the `IndexOf` fails when you use a string?

Comment: It would seem it treats a string with only a soft hyphen in it as an empty string (which is suppose to return 0).

Comment: It's because it's a zero width character, as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/4893256/1658168

Comment: Does this answer your question? [strange string.IndexOf behavour](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4893216/strange-string-indexof-behavour)

Comment: why do you use `Convert.ToChar(173)` instead of `(char)173`? But better use `char.ConvertFromUtf32(173)` which returns a string directly and works for all Unicode values include ones outside the BMP